# How to set HTML max width the same on both computer and mobile

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I am creating an email template in HTML and, while it displays properly on mobile, it is too wide on desktop. Currently it looks like this on my PC:

[image: My email template]

Here is an example that I would like to mimic. Notice how the width is the same on dekstop as it is on mobile:

[image: Morning brew]

**How can I accomplish this in HTML/CSS?**

I tried changing the attributes of my div class, but it did not work thus far.

Comment: You should include the CSS you have that sets the max-width, if you want the style to apply all the time, don’t set the style in a media query, it looks like the max width may be being applied inside a media query

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see some code.

Still, one solution is to wrap all of the content, except the header and footer, in one big container, that is a flexbox with a style of `flex-flow: column; align-items: center;` and give each child to have a maximum width.

Another solution is each section to be wrapped by two blocks (for semantics - wrap a  over a ), and have the inner div to have a maximum width and margins to the left and right of `auto`. All of this also wrapped in one big  or  (for semantics) with a style of `flex-flow: column; align-items: center;`.

Second solution can be redundant in many cases, but helpful in others. While setting up side margins to be auto is often a quick way to center a block element inside its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS media queries, they will help change the styles based on different screen resolutions:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
 }
}
```

You can choose `max-width` or `min-width` as your requirement. Another option is to use Bootstrap, for example:

```html
<div class='container-md'></div>
```